# Unable to save facebook login user details in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I'm trying to save user details in my database after facebook login. I'm using javascript SDK for it. I've made a callback through "onlogin". I think the problem is with my javascript code. Please refer to my code below.

Please help !!

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    function std() {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            var details = JSON.stringify(response);
            var name = details.first_name + details.last_name;
            var email = details.email;
            var gender = details.gender;
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "std.php",
            data: "&name="+name+ "&email=" +email+ "&gender=" +gender,
            success: function(){
                alert("Success");
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=AppID";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="3" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="std();">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

$connection = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
if (!$connection){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("database", $connection);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

$email = $_POST['email'];
$email  = mysql_real_escape_string($email);

$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$gender = mysql_real_escape_string($gender);

$sql = "INSERT INTO newmember VALUES ( '', '{$name}', '{$email}' ,'{$gender}', '' ,'')";

$db->query($sql); 

mysql_close($connection);
```

Comment: declare variables out side FB.api funcition.

Comment: put ajax call after response. not out side Fb funciton

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {            
        });
        function std() {
            FB.api('/me', function (response) {

                //var details = JSON.stringify(response);
                 var details = response;
                var name = details.first_name + details.last_name;
                var email = details.email;
                var gender = details.gender;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "std.php",
                    data: "&name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&gender=" + gender,
                    success: function () {
                        alert("Success");
                    }
                });
            });

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=AppID";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="3" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="std();">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure about `var details = JSON.stringify(response);` ?

Comment: Tried it @ParthTrivedi, but that didn't help solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

add jQuery in the head of your html file, above your title.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```